RLS Policy in postgres ignoring OR operator and throwing 'unrecognized configuration parameter' when using 2 different config parameters
i am trying to create an RLS policy in postgres that uses 2 config parameters in separate OR conditions  without the need to define both of them for policy to work but i am getting error that askes for both params to be defined.
in the policy i am referring different config parameter:

user_param
company_param

one part of the condition is supposed to allow querying the full table if  'user_param' PARAM is set to 'true' without the need to define second parameter.
second part after OR is used to allow filtering the table when setting only company_param.
when i do something like this in the policy
 using( (current_setting('user_param') = 'true') OR (current_setting('company_param') = 'true') )ode here

i am able to query the table when only one param is defined.
but if one condition is replaced with an EXISTS statement - which is what i need
like this :
USING (((current_setting('user_param'::text) = 'true'::text) OR (EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM company c WHERE ((rls_test.company_id = c.company_id) AND (c.company_current_id = (current_setting('company_param'::text))::bigint))))))

than i am  obligated to set both params or else i receive an error :
ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "company_param" SQL state: 42704
any ideas why ?

Pass a default value to current_setting.

@Bergi thanks , ill give it a try . any idea why the policy behaves like this ?

Not sure, probably some sort of lazy evaluation where OR decides to start with one operand and not evaluating the other expression unless necessary?
